# I have integrated rtmp streaming media in an ionic application but video is not playing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I m building an ionic application where I am trying to integrated live streaming into my app using rtmp stream. It will open the player but the Video is not playing. 
Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-media',
templateUrl: 'media.html',
})
export class MediaPage {

  constructor() { 
   }

 start(){
 alert("start video");

  (<any>window).videoStreamer.streamRTMP
 ('rtmp://103.130.188.26:1935/ntv/live/live1',alert('success'), 

 alert('failed')).onConnectionSuccess((data)=>alert(data))
 .onError((data)=>alert(data));

  }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check your live stream url ? is it working properly ?

Comment: yes, It's working fine on vlc player

Comment: I have checked above url in VLC and its throwing error.

Comment: I just checked it and it's working fine. Media-> Open network stream -> network -> rtmp://103.130.188.26:1935/ntv/live/live1

Comment: Can you try this with latest version of vlc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup `HLS` on your `RTMP` and then play `HLS` `URL` in your app or web.